# HBase starts always a Zookeeper server

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

In Docker I have 2 containers:

- HBase
- Zookeeper

I am configuring hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
</property>
```

And:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

Start HBase master:

```
/usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase --config /usr/local/hbase/conf master start
```

But this command is creating a mini Zookeeper instance (https://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/HMasterCommandLine.html#158), is it normal?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When runnning HBase in standalone mode it runs all processes (Maser, RegionServer and Zookeeper) in one JVM. See line [155](https://hbase.apache.org/xref/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/HMasterCommandLine.html#155) as well as the [Hbase documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/standalone_dist.html). In this mode it will always start its own Zookeeper.

In addition to setting `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false`, you also need to run HBase in Pseudo-distributed or Distributed mode if you want to manage your own Zookeeper.

Comment: Ok I see, I am testing this way so. Maybe it's for this reason master port is always different at runtime?